# Queueing tracks with Spotify's iOS API

Tags: ios, spotify

Using Spotify's API for iOS Swift. Trying to build a music player, in which queue functionality is obviously needed. However, I find that Spotify's API is extremely limited. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

1) **Up Next**: Not possible using the API.

2) **Add To Queue**: While it's possible to add to queue, the song will always be added to the end of the queue. And since it's not possible to retrieve and/or modify the current queue, this function is more or less useless.

3) **Queue multiple URIs/songs**: This was apparently removed from the API 1 year ago. Queueing up songs one-by-one seems like a hack especially as one seemingly have to wait for metadata of each song to be retrieved before adding the next (at least that's what I've read. However, I haven't been able to make it work yet).

*How's it possible that the leading streaming company in the world has such a limited API in 2017?*

If anyone has any advice on how to achieve any of the above, please let me know.

Answer (score 2):

In case anyone else is experiencing the same challenges, I'll answer my own question.

3) **Queue multiple URIs/songs**: Solved this by creating a private Spotify Playlist using the API for the authenticated user. Whenever a user initiates a track, I'm replacing all current tracks within this playlist with new ones.

For **1)**, it's simply a matter of using the API to add a specific track at the next position relative to your current track index within the private playlist.

I believe there isn't really a great solution for **2)**, without manually keeping track of the songs you've put into queue.

EDIT 1: Relative to 1), I find that playing from SPTPlaylistSnapshot is extremely unstable when modifying/adding songs to the playlist. Therefore, I ended up not implementing Up Next. Instead, I implemented Spotify's standard Add To Queue functionality, which works perfectly well with the configuration described for 3).

EDIT 2: Nevermind. All suggested solutions in the above proved to be to unstable, and can by no means used in production.